# First passage time for state transitions expressed in Laplace space?

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm struggling to understand the reasoning between moving between two steps in a biophysical reaction scheme for a paper I am reading. For this (from the description), the probabilities over different paths are summed, and the first passage-time distribution of completing the irreversible step ($irr$) is written in Laplace space as:

$$\Psi_{irr}(s) = \sum^\infty_{n=0}(\frac{k_{post}}{s+k_{in}+k_{post}}\frac{K_{pre}}{s+K_{pre}+K_{irr}})^n\times\frac{k_{post}}{s+k_{in}+k_{post}}\frac{K_{irr}}{s+K_{pre}+K_{irr}}$$

$$=\frac{K_{irr}k_{post}}{(s+k_{in}+k_{post})(s+K_{pre}+K_{irr})-(K_{pre}k_{post})}$$

I'm trying to go through reviews for Laplace space but, for me the math is just not clicking. I don't get how the summation above, multiplied by the final irregular step, yields the second part of the  expression? Any help or guidance on where to look would be greatly appreciated, as I've been struggling with this for a bit now. I get that it connects to markov models and transversing states according to probabilities defined by the rates $K_x$, maybe I'm missing something important related to Laplace space (which is a new area for me)? How does the first part simplify to the second?

Also, I hope I'm posting in an appropriate place for this question.

Thank you.